# How to serve static assets in Lagom?

Tags: java, playframework, lagom

I am trying to serve static assets with Lagom. I added a play router using [additional routers](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/AdditionalRouters.html) because play has support for serving assets from public folder.

But I can't use [`Assets.at`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AssetsOverview#Using-assets-with-configuration) function here because it is not static. After compiling code, I also don't see the assets jar, play suppose to create.

```
public class FileServerRouter implements SimpleRouter {

  private final Router delegate;

  @Inject
  public FileServerRouter(RoutingDsl routingDsl) {
    this.delegate =
        routingDsl
            .GET("/assets/*file")
            .routingTo(
                (request, file) -> {
                  // Assets.at(file);
                  return ok("Serving " + file);
                })
            .build()
            .asScala();
  }

  @Override
  public PartialFunction<RequestHeader, Handler> routes() {
    return delegate.routes();
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to use `Assets.at` with `RoutingDsl` or any other way to serve static assets with lagom?